# Discord python bot can't kick

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So this is a code to kick a member I've tried using, but it just doesn't work, what is going wrong here?

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member = discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
    await ctx.send("{} was kicked for the reason: {} by {}".format(member,reason,ctx.author.name))
    await member.send()

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        x = ""
        for i in MissingPermissions:
            x = x + i + "\n"
        await ctx.send("You don't have the following permissions: {}".format(x))
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: That's another problem - I get no traceback

Comment: It gives absolutely no errors so I can't even identify the problem

Comment: Try to replace `member = discord.Member` with `member: discord.Member` and remove `await member.send()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have to use `pass_context = True` anymore just leave empty `()` ([changelog in documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#context-changes)).
2. Replace `member = discord.Member` with `member : discord.Member`.
3. Remove `await member.send()` - you are not using it anyway.

### Corrected code

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} was kicked for the reason: {reason} by {ctx.author.name.mention}")

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        x = ""
        for i in discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions:
            x = x + i + "\n"
        await ctx.send(f"You don't have the following permissions: {x}")
    elif isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(str(error))
```

I corrected your code and added the newest string formatting method (`f"{something}"`) you might want to [read about it.](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) I also added [`.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.Member.mention) which mentions members and added another check for `kick_error()`.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, I knew about f strings but I like using .format. But thanks a ton i got it now!